# JVM crash during Weblogic Server Start and huge error log

Tags: java, server, weblogic

I am using Weblogic 10.3.6 and deployed few applications. I always do a clean stop start with the server. Suddenly one day when I am starting my server, it goes until 97% and then the JVM is getting crashed, and JAVA process stops and the server is unable to start from then. I tried to investigate from the WLS log file but it has nothing much except the JVM crash report. Also I saw there are many error logs which were mainly related to one of my application (like dispatcher servlet, struts2 error .. fileNotFound error etc).

Is it due to the huge application error getting piled up which is causing the JVM restart ? I have removed all the temp and cache. Restarted my machine but still unbale to start the weblogic server. Is there any way to start it ? I am not willing to delete the domain and create it again because there are so many configurations present.

Comment: You are going to have to post up some of the errors form the log, without them very hard to diagnose what is happening. In the meantime have a look at your domain config (i.e. \Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\config\config.xml) and make sure that that file is not corrupted. You should also make a backup of it in case you need to get back to that config at a later date.

Comment: Yup.. but as the errors were all related to one of my deployed application and theye were huge in numbers so I didnot paste it here. I checked the config.xml file and it was not corrupted, and just removed my erroneous application and it solved my problem. Thanks !!

Comment: NP Back up that config just in case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the erroneous application from the list of deployed application from file config.xml inside domain_name/config folder. Then gave a server start and my WLS started fine. The issue was due to the faulty application. Thanks I did not have to delete the entire domain. But I could not establish as why there was a JVM crash and how shall I handle it from next time.